# Turn a search & replace regex one liner, with counters, into a function with a for next or while loop

Tags: functions

this post has been simplified and re-written here:
[Making a function work with a loop](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31547/making-a-function-work-with-a-loop?noredirect=1#comment57873_31547)

I have this one liner, which takes the regex pattern match and replaces it with a string and a couple of counters:

```
let a=35 | let b=2 | g/[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}/s//\=a.'_PART__'.b/ | let a=a+1 | let b=b+1
```

eg a file containing this

```
10_20
20_30
30_40
40_50
10_20
20_30
30_40
40_50
```

becomes a file containing this

```
35_PART__2
36_PART__3
37_PART__4
38_PART__5
39_PART__6
40_PART__7
41_PART__8
42_PART__9
```

Here is what it does,
1 searches for regex   `[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}`
2 replaces regex with   `a.'_PART__'.b`
where
`a` starts at 35 and increments by 1 for each line in the file
`b` starts at 2 and increments by 1 for each line in the file

How can I express this in a `.vimrc` function with a for next loop or a while loop?
.. and how does the one liner know intrinsically to loop through each line in the file, which it does, whereas a function expressed as the distinct parts of the one liner does not)

This function works:

```
function ReplaceAndIncriment() abort
  let a=35
  let b=2 
  g/[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}/s//\=a.'_PART__'.b/ | let a=a+1 | let b=b+1
endfunction
```

But how can I make the function work, with all lines seperated and on differemt lines, as shown below, and use a for next, or, while do loop?

```
function ReplaceAndIncriment() abort
  let a=35
  let b=2 
  g/[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}/s//\=a.'_PART__'.b/
  let a=a+1
  let b=b+1
endfunction
```

Comment: It sounds like you're overlooking the `:g` command in the one liner. Looping over all buffer lines (and running the following command on those lines that match the associated pattern) is exactly what it does. `:h :g`.  And you can use it in your vimrc, too. :)

Comment: Thanks. Curious though .. when I seperated between <bar> commands into distinct lines in a function, it does not work.

Comment: I've added the failed function in an edit to the OP above. How could I get a line seperated function as shown to work?

Comment: Because `:g` considers everything that follows it _on its own line_ as part of the command(s) to be executed on each matching line...bar or no bar. That's how the two variables get incremented properly. If you join those three lines in the function it'll work there, too.

Comment: See `:h :bar` for list of commands that don't recognize bar as a command separator in quite the same way as other commands do. With `:g` bar is still a command separator but completely in the context of `:g` execution.

Comment: Thanks. I generally get what `:g` does, and do indeed see that the function as edited ie `g/[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}/s//\=a.'_PART__'.b/ | let a=a+1 | let b=b+1` does work. Just curious to know how I would do this with a for next loop, or while loop, with everything spread on different lines

Comment: I suggest you redo your question so that is the sole focus, then. Remove those parts that you've figured out so they don't distract. That function will not have `:g` anymore since the loop is replacing it's functionality. It will still have the `:s` command, of course, (or it's builtin function equivalent.)

Comment: Feel free to [edit] the question to make the clarifications suggested by BLayer. I found that it doesn't alter the core of the question (but rather clarifies), so I think posting a separate question is not very constructive. I closed the second one as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really drop the `|`s inside a `:g` command without changing the behavior. Some commands such as `:g` take the `|` as part of their arguments, which means breaking them into newlines doesn't result in the same command. (See [`:help :bar`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar) and note that `:global` is in the list of such commands.)

If the line length is an issue, you can break lines using backslashes for continuation. In Vimscript it's a little odd in that the backslash goes in the beginning of the continuation line.

In your case:

```
function! ReplaceAndIncrement() abort
  let a=35
  let b=2 
  g/[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}/
      \ s//\=a.'_PART__'.b/
      \ | let a=a+1
      \ | let b=b+1
endfunction
```

Note that you still need the `|`s, since this is essentially a single `:g` command executing a sequence of commands for each matching line. But hopefully line continuations will help you deal with the line length of such a command in an acceptable way.

Comment: that is a great answer, can it be done by dropping the `g` making it linewise and using a loop?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know i could use ``\`` for line continuation in vim. Good to know :)

Comment: You can't really use `:g` together with a `for` or `while`, they're different... If you use a traditional loop, you'll have to find a different way to find matching lines (e.g. the `search()` function, or one of the `match()` functions looping line by line, etc.) The code would be completely different at that point and a whole rewrite, so I don't see why you'd do that if `:g` does the job perfectly...

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Appreciated. Also I think you are spot on about the second post being a confusing replicate, which is why I have deleted it. I understand use of `g` is more efficient than a loop. I'm asking about the loop becasue (1) I am curious as to why this is so difficult to do, & (2) I had a good look into this and made quite a few attempts at using a loop to replace `g`, with no luck so far. While doing so I got bogged down in syntax minutiae / confusion, on a number of terms during my tests. I'll delve into `search()` and `match()` and see where I get / come back to it later.

Comment: @Kes Certainly `:g` is more convenient and in that way "easier" than a loop. But really, other than being more verbose a loop is not harder it's just different.  As for which is more (runtime) efficient that depends on how things were implemented and optimized in Vim. The only way to know is to test both and compare. (And though not likely it's actually possible the "winner" may depend on what OS the testing is done on.) FYI.